# Are there scripts or tools to help to migrate Flow to TypeScript automatically?

Tags: typescript, react-native, flowtype, migrate

I have an old react-native module using Flow. There are several thousand lines of code. Now, I would like to migrate these codes to a new project using TypeScript. I am looking for an auto-tool to help me solve tedious type-converting works. If it would solve about 90% of problems, I would appreciate it. 
For example,

- Changing all the `.js` file to '`ts` or `tsx` file, like:

```
for f in `find . -type f -name '*.js'`;
do
git mv -- "$f" "${f%.js}.ts"
done
```

- convert types

```
// Flow
import type { Type1, Type2 } from ./dir/to/path
// Typescript
import { Type1, Type2 } from ./dir/to/path
```

```
// Flow
type Date = {
  toString: () => string,
  setTime: (time: number) => number
}

// TypeScript
interface Date {
  toString(): string;
  setTime(time: number): number;
}

// Flow 
value: ?string 
// TypeScript 
value: string | null
```

Any suggestions?

---

At last, I used [flow-to-ts](https://github.com/Khan/flow-to-ts)

```
yarn global add @khanacademy/flow-to-ts
flow-to-ts --write --delete-source ${myProjectPath}/src/**/**.js
```

There are other options:

```
Usage: flow-to-ts [options]

Options:
  -V, --version                    output the version number
  --inline-utility-types           inline utility types when possible, defaults to 'false'
  --prettier                       use prettier for formatting
  --semi                           add semi-colons, defaults to 'false' (depends on --prettier)
  --single-quote                   use single quotes instead of double quotes, defaults to 'false' (depends on --prettier)
  --tab-width [width]              size of tabs (depends on --prettier) (default: 4)
  --trailing-comma [all|es5|none]  where to put trailing commas (depends on --prettier) (default: "all")
  --bracket-spacing                put spaces between braces and contents, defaults to 'false' (depends on --prettier)
  --arrow-parens [avoid|always]    arrow function param list parens (depends on --prettier) (default: "avoid")
  --print-width [width]            line width (depends on --prettier) (default: 80)
  --write                          write output to disk instead of STDOUT
  --delete-source                  delete the source file
  -h, --help                       output usage information
```

Comment: have you tried [`flow-to-ts`](https://dev.to/danielhauser/convert-a-react-app-from-flow-to-typescript-without-losing-git-history-32i1)?

Comment: Hi, I used it. There is an error.  `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)   at cli.js:79:23`

Comment: I see. I should use file globs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming),  instead of the directory path.